# How do you route to a show method using an alternative name?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I'm working on a Rails 3 project with the model called "recover"

I've created the following route that works. It routes to the index as I expect:

> match 'checkedin' => 'recovers#index',
>   :as => 'checkedin'
>
> link_to 'index', checkedin_path

How do I route to the id of the show method? The following code is my attempt, but it does not function. What am I doing wrong?

> match 'checkedin/:id' =>
>   'recovers#show', :as
>   =>'checkedin_show'
>   link_to 'show', checkedin_show_path(@recovers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could it be you meant to write

```
link_to 'show', checkedin_show_path(@recover)
```

Notice the argument is `@recover` (without the "s").

Comment: obvious! I can't believe I missed that.

Answer (score 0):

David Sulc's answer seems like the right one. My question is "Why aren't you using resources for this?"

Your route would be an easy `resources :recovers, :path => 'checkedin'` (... and you should add an underscore to checked_in to match typical Rails conventions). You'd get these routes:

```
    recovers GET    /checkedin(.:format)           
             POST   /checkedin(.:format)           
 new_recover GET    /checkedin/new(.:format)       
edit_recover GET    /checkedin/:id/edit(.:format) 
     recover GET    /checkedin/:id(.:format)       
             PUT    /checkedin/:id(.:format)       
             DELETE /checkedin/:id(.:format)
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to create method

```
def show 
@post = Post.find(params[:id])
end
```

or

on control page that you create

```
before_action :set_post, only: [:show, :edit]
```